# How to fix 'querySrv EREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.crf1-o7dqz.gcp.mongodb.net' MondoDB Atlas error connection?

Tags: windows, mongodb, mongoose, connectivity

At connection to `MongoDB Atlas` gives an error:

```
{ 
Error: querySrv EREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.crf1-o7dqz.gcp.mongodb.net     at

 QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:196:19)         
    errno: 'EREFUSED',   
    code: 'EREFUSED',   
    syscall: 'querySrv',   
    hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.crf1-o7dqz.gcp.mongodb.net' 
    }
```

Source:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect
('mongodb+srv://UserName:Password_@crf1-o7dqz.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', 
    { useNewUrlParser: true })
      .then(() => console.log('Database connected'))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

The same error (`querySrv EREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.crf1-o7dqz.gcp.mongodb.net`) appears when connecting to `MongoDB Compass`.

I tried running this code on `Ubuntu`, and everything worked well.

The error appears only on my `Windows`.

What is the reason for this error?